# Can Datagrid serve as a Datasource to Reportviewer?

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview

is it possible to make the datagrid items as datasource in dataset in the reportviewer? im trying but no luck.

this code return error "Cannot Find table 0."

```
 Dim dt As DataTable = ds4.Tables(0)
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        ds4.Tables(0).Rows.Add("-", "0", "0", "0")
        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds4
        Dim datasource As New ReportDataSource("DataSet3", ds4.Tables("1"))
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource)
    Next
```

Comment: ive found a way on how to get this done.    here is the code i used Dim dt As DataTable = ds4.Tables.Add("123")
        Dim acctid = New DataColumn("account_title", GetType(String))
        Dim rate = New DataColumn("rate", GetType(Double))
        Dim amt = New DataColumn("amount", GetType(Decimal))

        dt.Columns.Add(acctid)
        dt.Columns.Add(rate)

        dt.Columns.Add(amt)

        Dim datasource As New ReportDataSource("DataSet3", ds4.Tables(0))
        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds4.Tables("123")
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Me.DataGridView1.DataSource` to obtain a `DataSet` or a `DataTable` and create a `ReportDataSource`.

Comment: yep. ive used the datagrid to fill the data table then set as datasource to the reportviewer. thanks BTW